# In Latex, for \documentclass[table]{article}, what does the [table] mean?

Tags: pdftex

I find a problem in my document, for `\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear,table]{elsarticle}`, I have to add `[table]`, otherwise, the color table can not be shown. I do not understand why it does not work when I use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: The options given in `\documentclass` are global options which should apply to every package, so this effectively will result in `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. Most likely you're having some code you don't show that already loaded `xcolor`, but without the `table` option. Try using `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` directly after `\documentclass{elsarticle}` (also, you should've got an error from `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` if the `table` option doesn't have an effect there). All in all, we can only guess what's going wrong since you don't show us a document demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @Skillmon I believe your comment is one of a best suggestion, can you make this as `answer`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi but it really isn't an answer. It's a wild guess. And while the parts not being a wild guess might be factually correct, they are no answer for the stated question.

Comment: @Skillmon, yes, you are right, I have done as your advice, and it works, thank you very much.